# First in first out c++ algorithm

Tags: c++

Ive been asked to write a code to calculate average waiting time and average turn around time of Cpu algorithms. FIFO, SJF, RR and priority based scheduling. Im supposed to read from a text file which looks something like this... except its a lot longers.. around 2100 processes.

```
Process Arrival Burst   Priority
p1       31      9       41
p2       35      21      36
p3       6       55      61
p4       42      50      13
p5       36      85      58
```

Ive managed to read from the file into a 2D array.. But i have no clue how im supposed to use the array to do those calculations.. I m not thorough with the whole pointers thing. So.. is there anyway to do these calculations without use of pointers? This is the code ive written so far..

```
int main()
{
    string text[15][4]; 
    string f_comp[15][4];

    ifstream stream1("D:\\College\\OS\\OSassignment_sol\\idiot.txt");   
    if(!stream1)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot read file\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!stream1.eof())               
    {
        for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                stream1>>text[i][j];    
            }

        }

    }  


    //Checking if the stream has been assigned into the array correctly.
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            cout<<text[i][j]<<"\t";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    int z;
    cin>>z;
}
```

Comment: It is. Not asking for a code. Just guide lines :p coz im stuck.

Comment: You should really do some more programming in your free time. If this simple programming task is in the way of your OS course, then you are in for a rough ride for every new course. Off topic to your question maybe, but quite relevant for your future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to implement each one of those scheduling algorithms and write some kind of simulator.

Instead of using arrays, as I always find it hard to remember what goes where, consider using a struct.

```
struct Process {
    std::string name;
    int arrival;
    int burst;
    int priority;
};
```

Then you can choose an appropriate data structure for whatever scheduling algorithm you're using. The simulator should probably do something like this...

1. Place any processes that should be started at this time into the runnable queue
2. Schedule if something needs to happen (either due to a timer interrupt or the current process waiting)
3. Decrement currently running processes burst time (since it has run for an additional tick)
4. Add one to the current time
5. Repeat until finished

If you can do this in whatever language you want, it might be easier to use a scripting language, as this probably isn't performance critical (a real scheduler would be).

I would suggest you don't use arrays though, as they can get very confusing. Even if this were C I would still suggest using a struct for the processes instead of an array.

In particular, FIFO is a pretty easy one. You just keep the active processes in a list/vector structure and keep running until the burst is 0. Then you pop the front of the container and do the same until you run out of processes.

To keep the wait time, you can just count how many processes are currently in the wait queue every tick and average that together. For turnaround time, you can keep what tick a process was added and when it's finished, compute how long it took for the process to finish. Then add that time to whatever average you're keeping.

Comment: Ok, glad I checked for new answers before typing mine in, because I was just about to say the same thing.  I will add this much: allocate a new process struct for each line in the file and put them all in a std::list collection.  Then sort the list based on arrival time.  From this you can feed the events into your simulated scheduling algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this easier if you create a struct to represent the processes:

```
struct Process
{
    std::string name_;
    int arrival_, burst_, priority_;
};
```

You then should create a `std::vector<Process> processes` and `push_back()` to add new values from your input:

```
Process process;
while (std::cin >> process.name_ >> process.arrival_ >> process.burst_ >> process.priority_)
    processes.push_back(process);
```

You then need to use the numbers to simulate each of the scheduling policies, collecting statistics on the units of time (arrival_ and burst_ are seemingly in arbitrary units of time) between arrival_ time and completion: that is, the time when burst_ units of work have been completed for that process.

For example, for FIFO, you effectively sort the processes vector by arrival_ time, then iterate over them in order of ascending arrival time. The process with lowest arrival_ starts without waiting, and completes after burst_.  The next job's start time therefore can't be before the first job's completion time: arrival_ + burst_: if that second job arrives earlier then you accumulate its waiting time for your result, otherwise the second job doesn't have to wait either.  Keep repeating for all jobs.

Some of the other algos will be more complicated: for example, for SJF you need to keep track of which jobs are waiting each time the scheduling simulation completes a previous job, as it will select the shortest burst_ value from that set of jobs to be the next-executed process.